# Not able to start my laptop after nvidia driver install

Tags: 11.04, nvidia

I have a dell inspiron N5110, with i5, 4Gb ram and nvidia GT525 graphic card.

I installed ubuntu 11.04. It was working fine with unity. Then in **additional driver** I installed the recommended nvidia drivers. None of the nvidia drivers being used at that moment.

Next I restart to complete the driver installation as mentioned. Now the problem is after I pass the grub screen nothing happens and the caps lock key keeps on blinking.

I even tried to start into recovery mode, there also I'm unable to boot into Linux.

The only thing I can do is boot into linux via previous kernel install of the linux, from the grub menu.

Answer (score 1):

The GT525M is a nVidia Optimus card, you won't be able to use the driver from Ubuntu out-of-the-box. See also [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)

Comment: ....  GT425M or GT525 or both? :)

Comment: Both I guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot, never found a problem and solution for this. Maybe the Nvidia GT525M, is not supported at all.